# Software rendering is used instead of Nvidia GPU (1060) on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, opengl

I have issues with Nvidia 1060 GTX not being used by the OS. This has started after a recent regular update.

Os Ubuntu 18.04.4. I don't use any sort of VM. This is my desktop.

I would really appreciate your help in fixing this since I've already spent quite some time with completely zero efficiencies.

Output of **inxi -G**

```
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
               Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) drivers: nvidia (unloaded: modesetting,nouveau)
               Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
               OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 256 bits) version: 3.3 Mesa 19.1.4 (git-b84ffa028d)
```

Output of **glxinfo -B**

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.1.4 (git-b84ffa028d)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 19.1.4 (git-b84ffa028d)
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 19.1.4 (git-b84ffa028d)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

[/var/log/Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.com/0xAqLQuN)

[xorg.conf.d](https://pastebin.com/bNUaRqni) was generated by the last nvidia driver install. No success without it either.

Tested drivers:

1. **435.21 from the official repo**
2. **390 from NVIDIA website.** Using them now
3. **nouveau**. Results are similar (llvmpipe used as a renderer)

Tried different **display managers**. gdm3, lightdm, kde (using now)

Comment: I have tried completely reinstalling the system. Formatted the drive. I thought I might have messed up something in the boot partition. But nope. This thing is 100% reproducible for me. After 2 days I again have only software OpenGL available.

Comment: thanks for posting your question, I actually have the same problem, could you derive a solution?